# How can I correctly install the extend QrScanner

Tags: codenameone

I already installed the extend, but the documentation says that I have to reload the app (I've tried everything and can't do it), before it was only necessary to refresh the CN1Libs, how should I do it now?

[image]

```
    private void lectorCodigoQR() {
        if (CodeScanner.isSupported()) {
            CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {

                @Override
                public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
                    // Mostrar
                }
                @Override
                public void scanCanceled() {
                    System.out.println("cancelled");
                }
                @Override
                public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
                    System.out.println("err " + message);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Dialog.show("Error", "Su dispositivo no soporta el lector de QR", "Continuar", null);
        }
    }
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.innova507.taxi507</groupId>
        <artifactId>taxi507</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.innova507.taxi507</groupId>
    <artifactId>taxi507-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <!-- Add your cn1lib dependencies to this section -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
            <artifactId>codenameone-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>taxi507-cn1-codescan</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.innova507.taxi507</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- INJECT DEPENDENCIES -->
    </dependencies>

    <!-- The following are profiles to cover special cases -->
    <profiles>

        <!-- A profile to install Codename One support libraries to your home directory
        if they aren't installed yet. -->
        <profile>
            <id>install-codenameone</id>
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <missing>${user.home}/.codenameone/guibuilder.jar</missing>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>

                                    <target name="install-cn1">
                                        <available file="${user.home}/.codenameone/guibuilder.jar" property="codenameone.present"/>

                                        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.codenameone"/>
                                        <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/codenameone/tmpProject"/>
                                        <get src="https://www.codenameone.com/files/updates/UpdateCodenameOne.jar"
                                             dest="${user.home}/UpdateCodenameOne.jar"
                                             skipexisting="true"/>
                                        <java jar="${user.home}/UpdateCodenameOne.jar" fork="true">
                                            <arg value="${project.build.directory}/codenameone/tmpProject"/>
                                            <arg value="force"/>
                                        </java>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
        <!-- A profile to add kotlin support.  Activated if the src/main/kotlin
        directory exists -->
        <profile>
            <id>kotlin</id>
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <!-- To enable Kotlin, add the following file to the project base dir -->
                    <exists>${basedir}/src/main/kotlin</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
                <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-annotations-jvm -->
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
                    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                    <version>13.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java-runtime</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <files>
                                        <file>${basedir}/codenameone_settings.properties</file>
                                    </files>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>compile</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sourceDirs>
                                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                                    </sourceDirs>
                                    <args>
                                        <arg>-no-reflect</arg>
                                        <arg>-no-jdk</arg> <!-- No JDK -->
                                    </args>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-compile</id>
                                <goals> 
                                    <goal>test-compile</goal> 
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sourceDirs>
                                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                                    </sourceDirs>
                                    <args>
                                        <arg>-no-reflect</arg>
                                        <arg>-no-jdk</arg> <!-- No JDK -->
                                    </args>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        

        <profile>
            
            <id>javase</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>codename1.platform</name>
                    <value>javase</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javase</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <longClasspath>true</longClasspath>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-Xmx1024M</argument>
                                <!--<argument>-Xdebug</argument>
                                <argument>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=n</argument>-->
                                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                <classpath />
                                <argument>${exec.mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>${cn1.mainClass}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- 
                For running in simulator in process use:
                mvn cn1:java -P simulator
                            
                Fro running in simulator in forked process use:
                mvn cn1:simulator -P simulator
            -->
                
            <id>simulator</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javase</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
            
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending iOS debug builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P ios-debug
            -->
            <id>ios-debug</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- Build server target type -->
                <codename1.targetType>iphone</codename1.targetType>
                
                <!-- Used for identifying native interfaces.  Should match correct subdirectory of native -->
                <codename1.targetPlatform>ios</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending iOS debug builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P ios-release
            -->
            <id>ios-release</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- Build server target type -->
                <codename1.targetType>iphone</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.production>true</codename1.production>
                
                <!-- Used for identifying native interfaces.  Should match correct subdirectory of native -->
                <codename1.targetPlatform>ios</codename1.targetPlatform>
                <codename1.appStoreBuild>true</codename1.appStoreBuild>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Javascript builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P javascript
            -->
            <id>javascript</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>javascript</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javascript</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Android builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P android
            -->
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>android</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>android</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Windows UWP builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P uwp
            -->
            <id>uwp</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>windows</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>win</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Windows desktop builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P windows
            -->
            <id>windows</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>desktop_windows</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javase</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Mac Desktop builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P mac
            -->
            <id>mac</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>desktop_macosx</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javase</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>${basedir}/codenameone_settings.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
                <artifactId>codenameone-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-gui-sources</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-gui-sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cn1-process-classes</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compliance-check</goal>
                            <goal>css</goal>
                            <!--<goal>compile-javase-sources</goal>-->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-test-artifact</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-test-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>


        </plugins>


    </build>

    
</project>
```

I have included an image of the tree where it shows the menu on the pom and I don't see a way to update it. I am also including the pom.xml (if it has the extension included)

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LVBZPMCTTTEZxEYfwrh3S2_fPzyktTiN

Comment: What's the "Extended QrScanner"? Do you mean the littlemonkey QR or something else?
Are you using Ant or Maven? What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the "Codename One CodeScanner Library" extension.

I am using Maven / Netbeans and as the image shows the extension is already present, however I cannot import the libraries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you refresh maven? How is the dependency expressed in the POM?

Comment: The truth so far is that I'm getting to know Maven and CSS (because of the CN1 change). I would appreciate indications on how to refresh.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with NetBeans. In intellij there's just an option in the right click menu on the pom file. But a quick search didn't bring up a similar NetBeans feature. If you build from the command line does this work? How does the dependency look in the pom.xml file?

Comment: I have included an image of the tree where it shows the menu on the pom and I don't see a way to update it. I am also including the pom.xml (if it has the extension included).

Comment: Look under the tools submenu and maven submenu. I asked Steve if he might have something here. I suggest trying to build with the mvn command line to see if this is a NetBeans problem or a Maven problem.

Comment: Try editing the pom files slightly (newline etc) and saving to see if this will trigger a refresh. Also try opening the common project as a standalone project. Editing and trying to build that on its own. The command line might also help if you can try building using that.

Comment: I have tried all the suggestions, but to no avail. I copy a link to a video I made to validate the steps because I have not found to make it work. The video doesn't show it, but in the end I close and open the project trying to refresh.

I appreciate if you could perform a test in Netbeans / Windows environment to detect the problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear. I'll check if Steve has additional ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from Steve Hannha:

> I just created a fresh project in the cn1 intializr with "NetBeans" selected as the IDE.
>
> Opened project in NetBeans 12.3 on Windows 10.
>
> Opened CN1 Settings.
>
> Installed Codename One Scanner library.
>
> Initially the text editor wasn't giving me any autocomplete or error-underlines on anything, even from cn1 core classes.
>
> I right-clicked on the "common" module, and selected "Resolve Project Problems"
> I got a dialog with errors like "Some dependency artifacts are not in the local repository".
>
> When I pressed the "Resolve..." button in that dialog, it downloaded the dependencies and things started to magically work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it already recognizes the extension, but now I ran into the problem that it does not allow building the application. To clarify: the netbeans output window (console) shows the message "BUILD SUCCESS", but nothing new appears on the build server. Important: it does not show me the message of the temporary signature. I opted to sign the app, but it still won't let me build the app.

I've tried closing the application, exiting and re-entering netbeans, but get the same results.

Comment: Which maven target did you pick? Did you send a cloud build or use a local build?

Comment: This is something I've done many times with clean and build, using the cloud server.

Comment: Sure but the maven process is different since it also supports offline build. Maybe you picked the wrong target?

Comment: I tried it several times and it doesn't work. I'm about to quit maven. Can you create an app with the above method (using the designer)?

I'm going to open another question on stack overflow.

Comment: Did you run the `android-device` target? See https://shannah.github.io/codenameone-maven-manual/

What was the output in the console?